# Is there a way to resolve repeated server error problem in LaTex (Overleaf)?

Tags: overleaf

I ran into this error while trying to compile my overleaf latex;

"Server Error Sorry, something went wrong and your project could not be compiled. Please try again in a few moments".

Your response will be helpful. Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This problem may arise as a result of the internet connection. The simple way to resolve this problem is to reload the Overleaf editor by refreshing your browser.

Comment: Fwiw, this doesn't fix the problem for me. It occurs on many different wifi networks when other websites load fine.  It is transient and "streaky", occurring for 20 minutes, then going away, seemingly at random.